# Escaping username characters in basic auth URLs

Tags: http, basic-authentication

When using http basic authentication, the username can be passed in the URL, e.g.

```
http://david@foo.com/path/
```

But now suppose the username is an email address, e.g. david@company.com. Doing this is clearly ambiguous:

```
http://david@company.com@foo.com/path/
```

Is there a way to escape the @ character in the username? I tried standard URL encoding:

```
http://david%40company.com@foo.com/path/
```

But that didn't do it.

Comment: You can't use @ in URLs. Or did I got you wrong?

Comment: I know I'm a little late to the party, but did you simply miss the password part? the standard syntax should be `http(s)://user:pass@host`. So in your case it should be `http(s)://david%40company.com:Y0ur%24up3r%243cur3P%40%24%24w0rd@foo.com`.

Comment: @FatalMerlin you can have both the flavor with just username, and with both username & password. Though that is I think orthogonal to the escaping issue.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

According to [RFC 3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html), section 3.2.1, it needs to be percent encoded:

```
  userinfo    = *( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" )
```

So it looks like

```
http://david%40company.com@foo.com/path/
```

Is right. Where are you trying to read it? Maybe you need to manually decode the value?

Comment: I have my own server side code that processes the credentials. I need to debug it and see exactly what I receive when I escape this way. I'll follow up!

Comment: Clients don't appear to do well with that syntax. e.g. IE9 blocks it before even sending any request, and gives the error "Windows cannot find 'http://david%40company.com@foo.com/path/'. Check the spelling and try again.". This leads me to believe that this syntax is not actually supported, despite what it may seem from the RFC.

Comment: Interesting. We tried this exact syntax with a URL being fetched using Drupal's drupal_http_request, and it didn't let the user login. (We have since fixed the problem, but I came searching anyway out of academic interest.)