# Upload file to FTP via PHP's cURL, error because password contains '<' character

Tags: php, linux, curl, ftp

I've been using a piece of nifty PHP code to upload files to FTP via cURL.
It has served me well until today.

It returns a curl error #3 when I execute it
Intepretation of error: CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT (3) : The URL was not properly formatted. 
I figured it was because the password contains special characters.
The password contains a '<'
e.g. R3lHK2A9<1
This code works in the past where the passwords all consist of only letters and numbers.

I tried using `escapeshellarg()` , `urlencode()` and `escapeshellcmd()` to the password....in vain. Am I missing something?

Can you guys help please?

```
    <?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    $localfile = “test.tar”;
    $fp = fopen($localfile, ‘r’);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ‘ftp://username:password@ftp.domain.com/public_html/filesfromscript/’.$localfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));

    curl_exec ($ch);
    $error_no = curl_errno($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    if ($error_no == 0) {
    $message = ‘File uploaded successfully.’;
    } else {
    $message = “File upload error: $error_no. Error codes explained here http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html”;
    }
    echo $message;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 8):

Try using the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option to set the auth credentials, instead of passing then in the URL.

E.g.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://ftp.domain.com/public_html/filesfromscript/'.$localfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:pass<word');
```

Also (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718471/escaping-username-characters-in-basic-auth-urls)) you could try percent-encoding the auth credentials:

```
$username = 'username';
$password = 'pass<word';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://'.rawurlencode($username).':'.rawurlencode($password).'@ftp.domain.com/public_html/filesfromscript/'.$localfile);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set login/pass using CURLOPT_USERPWD option :

```
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_USERPWD, '[username]:[password]')
```