# Pass an e-mail into a HTTP login

Tags: python, http, authentication, request, splinter

I'm trying to make a login using only HTTP request. Like:

`http://user:password@mywebsite.com`

And everything works fine.

But there is this one username that is an e-mail. So, how should I pass them in HTTP? I'm trying

`http://myemail@mydomain.com:password@mywebsite.com`

And I know this is wrong, but it's the only idea I had. How should I do this?
I'm using python's *splinter* library to run some tests in my stuff.

In splinter, it should look like:

```
from splinter import *
browser = Browser('firefox')
browser.visit('http://myemail@mydomain.com:password@mywebsite.com')
```

And still nothing.

Comment: You need to urlencode, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718471/escaping-username-characters-in-basic-auth-urls

Comment: Instead of including the solution in your question, I suggest you post your answer *as an answer* (yes, you can answer your own question). Also, in your answer, include more info (link-only answers are not good answers, include the relevant details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT WORKS!

Well, it is working now, thanks to synotna's tip.
I'm using:

`http://myemail%40mydomain.com:mypassword@website.com`

And if you need to pass a port,

`http://myemail%40mydomain.com:mypassword@website.com:port`