# Java SFTP (apache vfs2) - password with @

Tags: java, sftp, apache-commons-vfs

I'm trying to use the org.apache.commons.vfs2 to download a file via SFTP.
The problem is, the password contains the '@' char, so this causes the URI to be parsed incorrectly:

```
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Expecting / to follow the hostname in URI
```

Does anyone has an idea how to get around this issue? (I can't change the password, obviously). This is the code I'm using:

```
String sftpUri = "sftp://" + userName + ":" + password + "@"
        + remoteServerAddress + "/" + remoteDirectory + fileName;

String filepath = localDirectory + fileName;
File file = new File(filepath);
FileObject localFile = manager.resolveFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(sftpUri, opts);
localFile.copyFrom(remoteFile, Selectors.SELECT_SELF);
```

Comment: Have another look at your `sftpUri`. What happens to the `remoteServerAddress` parameter if you password contains an @?

Comment: As I said, I know what the problem is (the URI is parsed incorectly because of the @ in the password). My question was how to solve it.

Comment: Sry. I didn't see. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718471/escaping-username-characters-in-basic-auth-urls

Comment: This might be a silly question, but how do encode the password?

Comment: You can use `URLEncoder.encode(...)` from `java.net`. Do only encode username and password.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [an actual URI constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) instead of hand-rolling your own:

```
String userInfo = userName + ":" + password;
String path = remoteDirectory + filename;  // Need a '/' between them?
URI sftpUri = new URI("sftp", userInfo, remoteServerAddress, -1, path, null, null);
...
FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(sftpUri.toString(), opts);
```

Comment: and make sure path starts with a / and does not use windows \ characters. Or you convert it from a file like this: `new File("c:\\temp").toURI().getPath()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the your password by `UriParser.encode()`, you can change your code like below:

you code:

```
String sftpUri = "sftp://" + userName + ":" + password + "@"
        + remoteServerAddress + "/" + remoteDirectory + fileName;
```

change to:

```
String sftpUri = "sftp://" + userName + ":" + **UriParser.encode(password, "@".toCharArray())**+ "@"
        + remoteServerAddress + "/" + remoteDirectory + fileName;
```

Hope it help, thank you.