# Http Request through proxy in python having @ in password

Tags: python, proxy

How to escape `@` character in the password of proxy. So that python can create the request correctly. I have tried `\\` but still not able to hit the url correctly.

```
 proxy = {
        "http": "http://UserName:PassWord@X.X.X.X:Port_No"
    }
```

**Update question:**

I am using python requests module for the http request. It split the string (to get host) from first occurrence of @ where as it was suppose to split from second @.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 335, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 438, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 327, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='XXXXXXXX@X.X.X.X', port=XXXXX): Max retries exceeded with url: http:/URL (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
```

Comment: Where is the second occurrence of `@` in your question?

Comment: one in th password and second is the seperator of password and ip i.e.  'username:st@ckoverflow@192.168.1.200:12345'

Comment: Huh?  I don't see that anywhere in your question. Regardless, this proxy works for me too: `http://username:st@ckoverflow@127.0.0.1:12345`. And have you tried `http://username:st%40ckoverflow@127.0.0.1:12345` yet?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do urlencoding like in this post:

[Escaping username characters in basic auth URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718471/escaping-username-characters-in-basic-auth-urls)

This way the @ in the PW becomes %40

Answer (score -1):

You don't mention which library you are using to perform your HTTP requests, so you should consider using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org), not only to solve this problem, but because it is a great library.

Here is how to use a [proxy](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies) with basic authentication:

```
import requests

proxy = {'http': 'http://UserName:PassWord@X.X.X.X:Port_No'}
r = requests.get("http://whereever.com", proxies=proxy)
```

**Update**

Successfully tested with requests and proxy URLs:

- `http://UserName:PassWord@127.0.0.1:1234`
- `http://UserName:PassWord@@127.0.0.1:1234`
- `http://User@Name:PassWord@1234@127.0.0.1:1234`

---

If, instead, you need to use Python's `urllib2` library, you can do this:

```
import urllib2

handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://UserName:PassWord@X.X.X.X:Port_No'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
r = opener.open('http://whereever.com')
```

Note that in neither case is it necessary to escape the `@`.

A third option is to set environment variables `HTTP_PROXY` and/or `HTTPS_PROXY` (in *nix).

Comment: I have updated the question and i do get the error when i use request module. And it works fine if i change the password without @

Comment: @Naresh: OK, I see that I have misunderstood the problem which is that the `@` is contained within the password field. Did you try to urlencode the URL as suggested by jhinghaus?

Comment: @Naresh: actually, it does work with a `@` in the password, i.e. 2 `@` characters such as `http://UserName:PassWord@1234@127.0.0.1:1234` and `http://User@Name:PassWord@1234@127.0.0.1:1234` etc. I am using requests version 1.2.3. What version are you using?