# How to add login credentials to URL

Tags: http, authentication, https, credentials

I tried https://myserver.com/~username=username&password=mypassword but it doesn't work.

Can you confirm that it's possible to pass the user/pass via HTTPs parameters (GET or POST)?

Basically, I want to access this link https://www.globalnorm.net/gn/doc.php?name=ASTM%20F%202638:2012-00&erx=0 (but I need to authenticate ) How can pass my username and password in URL?

Answer (score 26):

The standard method to pass basic authentication to web servers is to use a url of the form:

```
http://user:password@domain.com/
```

Web servers do not expect basic authentication in the query parameters. You can, of course, implement your own authentication using query parameters / HTTP headers or any other method.

#### Update

The specific URL you had supplied redirects to `https://www.globalnorm.net/login.php?ecd=S&info=nosessionorcookie&doc=...`.

The login path *does not* return the header `WWW-Authenticate` which is used to indicate that basic authentication is supported. So no point in trying HTTP basic authentication.

This specific login page seems to expect a POST request to `/login.php` with USR, PAS parameters. The answer will probably include a cookie which is later used to authenticate with the server.

Comment: i tired with POST Rest `https://www.globalnorm.net/gn/login.php?USR=moki@test.com&PAS=7PE6NzPdG&doc=ASTM%20F%202638:2012-00` but `<input id="USER" name="USR" type="text" value="">` `<input id="PASS" name="PAS" type="password" value="">` still empty and 
`<input id="doc" name="doc" type="hidden" value="ASTM F 2638:2012-00">` is filled

Comment: What if the password has `@` in it?

Comment: @fix - you need to percent-encode it. For `@` you need `%40`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718471/escaping-username-characters-in-basic-auth-urls).

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be some controversy about whether or not browsers have dropped the feature, and/or whether the feature is deprecated. But unless your browser has in fact dropped the feature, then as noted in @nimrodm's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50528734/467590) above, you can specify a url with basic authentication as

```
http://user:password@domain.com/
```

However, you really should not use http protocol, since that will send the credentials in clear text. Instead, just use:

```
https://user:password@domain.com/
```

Note that you must urlencode special characters in the user or password fields (I frequently use '@' in my passwords, so those must be written as '%40').

The browser extracts the credentials, and passes them to the server in an Authorization header:

```
Authorization: Basic credentials
```

where the credentials are simply the (url-decoded) string "username:password" as written in the url, but base64-encoded. But since the https connection is encrypted, the header is encrypted and the credentials are not exposed outside the browser.

I think the whole issue about removing support or deprecating the feature was based on the security implications of specifying the credentials using http protocol. But with the availability of free ssl certificates, and the push for "ssl everywhere", that no longer seems like much of a problem these days.

Of course there's also the issue of how much good passing credentials this way does you. Many or most applications that require login expect to get the credentials from a form the user fills out and sends with a POST request. The application would have to be written to check each request for an `Authorization` header, and if present, process the credentials the same way they would if they had been specified by a POST of a filled-out login form.

Applications that expect HTTP basic authentication generally are built with that requirement built into the server configuration, e.g. using Apache directives along theses lines:

```
<Directory "/htdocs/protected">
    AuthName "Registered User"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /lib/protected.users
    require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Where the file `/lib/protected.users` is a file of encrypted usernames and passwords generated by the Apache utility program `htpasswd`. With this configuration, any request for resources below `/htdocs/protected` is automatically checked by Apache for an `Authentication` header. If the request has no such header, or the credentials specified in the header do not match one of the pairs of usernames and passwords in `/lib/protected.users`, then the server responds with a `401 Unauthorized` status and a header:

```
WWW-Authenticate    Basic realm="Registered User"
```

Note that the realm value "Registered User" is the AuthName value from the Apache configuration. The browser handles this response by displaying a prompt requesting username and password, with the value of the realm contained in the prompt to give the user a hint as to what particular username and password is required.

Browsers have to treat the credentials specially anyway to convert them to an `Authorization` header, and so they also cache them and send them each time with requests to the same endpoint, like sending cookies. If they didn't do this, then the user would have to supply them on each subsequent url specifying that endpoint to avoid getting prompted.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The web server doesn't care about anything past the "?". This data gets sent to the application.

If you're actually authenticating to the application you would need to check the app's documentation for the correct parameter names.

In the past, you could supply the username:password@domain in the URL, but this has been disabled in many recent browsers because of security risks.

Currently, the only way I'm aware of to do an auto login is to set a basic auth header and do a form post, however you'll be better off to use a library that already knows how to do it, since the fields need to be encoded properly to work.

Comment: for the parameter name is correct my goal is access to the data without display the LOGIN PAGE

Comment: @MokiNex The username:password@domain syntax shown above no longer works. The browser vendors have disabled this functionality. The only way to provide the login info without the popup is by creating a proper auth header and doing a form post,

Comment: how to deal that what I need to put in the Header value Request_

Comment: I don't believe that you can prevent the Basic Authentication box from appearing unless you can modify the web page that you access right before the secure area.

Comment: java (snippet) and i use some KNIME NODE

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Java. Maybe someone else can help.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct in my assessment, the question is **Can you confirm that it's possible to pass the user/pass via HTTPs parameters (GET or POST)?**
Here is a snippet of code that I am using to send username and password as parameters to a GET call. Hope it helps.

```
 $('#button').click(function () {
            var username = $('#username').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("DesiredAction")?username=' + username + '&password=' + password;
        });
```