# HTTP basic authentication is not working due to “@” in password string, Even the encoding is not working

Tags: http, authentication, url, browser

HTTP basic authentication is not working due to “@” in password string.

Example - http://test:c@r20!9@rocket.io/

tried encoding the @ to %40 but not working for me.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping username characters in basic auth URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718471/escaping-username-characters-in-basic-auth-urls)

Comment: the http://username:password@example.com format is no longer supported by either IE or Chrome

Comment: What is the new format then?