# What is the correct way of passing proxy user and proxy password in python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using proxy in python requests and have followig question. The syntax

http://username:password@host:port

Does the usename and passowrd have to be encoded like quote(usrname) and quote(password) as the username and passowrd can have special chars like #, $ etc.

Does requests need encoding ?

Any github link would be helpful

Comment: what do you mean 'Does requests need encoding ?'

Comment: I mean do have to use the quote(username) syntax or just username is fine? I am confused because my usename having @ works fine without using quote and sending as is to requests

Comment: no quotes as per RFC

Comment: If no quote, then why the answer is showing encoding. Quote is the one from urllib

Answer (score 1):

you need to replace the special chars with HTML entities if you encounter a problem
according to here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6718568/12239849

```py
import urllib.parse
username = 'dav#id@company.com'
password = 'dddd^ff'
proxy = 'http://'+urllib.parse.quote(username)+':'+urllib.parse.quote(password)+'@foo.com/path/'
```

will return

```
http://dav%23id%40company.com:dddd%5Eff@foo.com:8080
```

Comment: Is this specific to python-requests also??

Answer (score 0):

You just need to setup you proxy like:

```py
# Import
import requests

# Proxy
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://username:password@host:port',
    'https': 'http://username:password@host:port'
} 

# Main thread
if __name__ == "main":
    r = requests.get("www.google.com", proxies=proxies)
```

This works with utf-8 encoding

Comment: What if the username has #, @ in it??