# How to use password with special character in Basic Auth

Tags: python, python-requests, special-characters, basic-authentication, python-telegram-bot

I'm using Python Telegram Bot API https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot behind the proxy.
So my task is to set proxy using Basic Auth.

It works perfectly next way:

```
REQUEST_KWARGS = {
    "proxy_url": "https://TechLogin:Pass@word!@192.168.111.38:5050/"  # proxy example
}

updater = Updater(token=my_bot_token, request_kwargs=REQUEST_KWARGS)
```

But SysAdmin changed password for TechLogin and now it contains some special characters:

```
new_login = "-th#kr123=,1"
```

and requests library (or even urllib3) can't parse it:

```
telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to parse: TechLogin:-th
```

Looks like it can't parse sharp symbol `#`

**How can I escape it ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL encoded values.

ex:-

```
# = %23
```

You can encode values to URL [here](https://www.urlencoder.org/).

```
"-th#kr123=,1" = "-th%23kr123%3D%2C1"



"proxy_url": "https://TechLogin:-th%23kr123%3D%2C1@192.168.111.38:5050/"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for response! Can you show the whole example please? Because just changing # to %23 doesn't work: `Tunnel connection failed: 407 authenticationrequired`. This means, urllib3 accept `%23` as 3 different symbols and says that password is incorrect

Comment: nope still doesn't work. I tried this solution also tried to set env var in the same way - always `407 authenticationrequired` :(

Comment: Also tried it using `curl` - curl can handle # (successfully connected!) but can't handle using URL-encoding...

Answer (score 0):

You must use **URL-encoding**, as shown in this post:

[Escaping username characters in basic auth URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718471/escaping-username-characters-in-basic-auth-urls)

This way the **#** in the password becomes **%23**

Comment: Hi, thank you for response! Can you show the whole example please? I get `Tunnel connection failed: 407 authenticationrequired.` Looks like urllib3 accepts %23 as 3 different symbols and says that password is incorrect